# Arithmetic expression error in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, bc

First i will take value of yesterday & Today file size in bytes (a=yesterday & b=today)

I need to calculate the percentage and find out if difference greater than or less than 10%

```
a=21007558 -- Yesterday
b=19330    -- Today 

c=`expr ((($b/$a) "*" 100) "-" 100) | bc`
```

This is not working

Comment: Note that, if this is your actual code, the variables `a` and `b` will be empty: `--` is not the shell's comment mechanism. You'll see this error: `bash: --: command not found`. I can explain further if requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use scale option as below;

```
c=$(echo "scale=6;((($b/$a) * 100) -100)" | bc)
echo $c
```

to lest than or greter than %10; you can try as below;

```
let c=$(echo $(printf %.$2f $(echo "scale=6;((($b/$a) * 100) -100)" | bc)))
if [[ c -lt -10  ]]; then
echo "decrease rate is %"$c    
fi
if [[ c -gt 10  ]]; then
echo "increase rate is %"$c    
fi
```

Comment: @senthil; I update ans. added if statement < or >  10%